# Can you transform the result of switchMap observable to get its value and not the observable itself?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, rxjs-observables, switchmap

I'm trying to create an in-memory singleton that holds the current vendor a person is browsing on.

A guard is used on all specific routes to catch the parameter:

```
canActivate(
  route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
  state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> {

  let currentUrl = this._router.url;
  const param = route.params['vendname'];

  return this._vendorService.getByName(param).pipe(map(a => {
    if (a == null) {
      this._snackBarService.open('Vendor not found', 'x', { duration: 5000 });
      return this._router.parseUrl(currentUrl);
    }
    return true;
  }));
}
```

A service is used to get the vendor by name. If it exists in-memory return it. If it doesn't, get it from the server first.

```
set vendor(value: IUser) {
  this._vendor.next(value);
}

get vendor$(): Observable<IUser> {
  return this._vendor.asObservable();
}

getByName(name: string): Observable<IUser> {
  const result = this.vendor$.pipe(map(v => {
    if (v != null && v.displayName == name) {
      return v;
    }
    else {
      return this.Get<IUser>(`api/vendor/${name}`).pipe(switchMap(v => {
        this.vendor = v;
        return of(v)
        // ...
      }));
    }
  }))
  return result;
}
```

The problem is I need to check `vendor$` for its value which returns an `Obervable<IUser>` but the switchMap also returns an `Obervable<IUser>`, causing the result to be `Observable<Observable<IUser>>`. How can I make the `result` return a single User Observable?

Comment: Return `v` instead of `of(v)`

Comment: ``return this.Get<IUser>(`api/vendor/${name}`).pipe`` always returns an observable, so need to use a swtich map in the vendors$ pipe as well ``this.vendor$.pipe(map(v => {``, but be aware you need to transform non observable returns in you switchmap to observables

Comment: Additionally: Why do you use ``this.Get<IUser>(`api/vendor/${name}`).pipe(switchMap(v => {`` ?  i cannot see a scenario for switchmap or is your code just shorter nd the ``...`` contains the real switchmap?

Comment: There is no subscription ever done on the call to `getByName` because it is called from my `guard`. So, I use switchmap that (as I am aware) does an inner-subscription.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are misunderstanding the use case of `switchMap()` becuase it's not the cause of your `Observable<Observable<IUser>>`. Your first `map()` operator inside `getByName()` is either returning a value of type `IUser` (when true) or an observable of `IUser` (when false). So `getByName()` returns either `Observable<IUser>` or `Observable<Observable<IUser>>`.

However, if you want to try to utilize replaying in-memory values from an observable, then I would recommend `shareReplay()`. Also, here's a recommended pattern for such a case.

```
private vendorName = new Subject<string>();

public vendor$ = this.vendorName.pipe(
  distinctUntilChanged(),
  switchMap(name=>this.Get<IUser>(`api/vendor/${name}`)),
  shareReplay(1)
)

public getByName(name:string){
  this.vendorName.next(name);
}
```

Then in the guard file.

```
canActivate(
  // ...
){
  let currentUrl = this._router.url;
  const param = route.params['vendname'];

  this._vendorService.getByName(param);

  return this._vendorService.vendor$.pipe(
    map(vendor=>{
      if(!vendor){
        this._snackBarService.open('Vendor not found', 'x', { duration: 5000 });
        return this._router.parseUrl(currentUrl);
      }
      return true;
    })
  );
```

With this setup, your component(s) & guard can subscribe to `vendor$` to get the `IUser` data it needs. When you have the name to get the vendor, you can invoke `getByName()`. This will trigger the following steps:

1. The `userName` subject will emit the new name.
2. The `vendor$` observable (subscribed to `userName`) will take that name, then switchMap to get the value from the inner observable (the `Get` method)
3. The `shareReplay(1)` ensures any subscription to `vendor$` (current or future) will get the last (1) emitted value from memory.

If you need to update the vendor name, just invoke `getByName()` with your new name and everything subscribed to `vendor$` will automatically get the updated value.

Comment: I couldn't get it to check if the name already exists before calling the server. I don't want to call the server on each angular route.

Comment: Apologies, I updated my example to fit with your use case. I added `distinctUntilChanged()` before calling the API. This prevents duplicate calls being made if `vendorName` emits a duplicate name. I also included the guard update that calls the method to emit the new param, then returns the same logic based on the last emitted value of `vendor$`.

Comment: That worked, BUT I still needed to be able to manually add the URL with a vendor name in the browser address bar. Also, I was getting strange behaviors when navigating. Change your `Subject` to `ReplaySubject<string>(1)` so that it only keeps track of the single value.

Answer (score 0):

related to what I see vendor$ is a stream of **IUser**, here is a refactoring of your code using **iif** rxjs operator to subscribe to the first or the second observable based on a your condition

```
 this.vendor$.pipe(
    mergeMap(v => iif(
      () => v && v.displayName == name, of(v), this.Get<IUser>(`url`).pipe(tap(v => this.vendor = v))
     )
    )
  )
```

Comment: This will only work if I explicitly `subscribe` to it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding another solution that worked.

Seeing as though the `canActivate` returns a `Promise` as well, you can also use the trusty old `async` `await` method.

Note: the `toPromise` is now `lastValueFrom` in rxjs 7.

```
async getByVendorName(name: string): Promise<IUser> {
  const v:IUser = await new Promise(resolve => { 
    this.vendor$.subscribe(a => {
      if (a != null && a.displayName.toLocaleLowerCase() == name) {
        resolve(a);
      }
    });
    resolve(null);
  });

  if (v == null) {
    return this.Get<IUser>(`api/vendor/${name}`).pipe(switchMap(v => {
      this.vendor = v;
      return of(v);
    })).toPromise();

  }
  return Promise.resolve(v);
}
```